# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call removeView() on the child's parent first while using RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have used `RadioGroup` to implement only one item to select from dynamically created radiobuttons.

```
    final LinearLayout firstRowTxtLayout = new LinearLayout(fContext);
    firstRowTxtLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    rbGroup.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rbButton = new RadioButton(fContext);
    rbButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rbButton.setId(rbTagincreament);
    rbGroup.addView(rbButton);
```

And `RadioGroup` I have initialized outside the loop. and added the `RadioGroup` view to another layout

I again changed it (shown below). Now I am getting the radio buttons, but I can select every button in the group.

```
            private void createRadioButton(int num) {
    Log.i("comVisa", "Num ==" + num);

    rg = new RadioGroup(fContext); // create the RadioGroup
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);// or RadioGroup.VERTICAL

    rb = new RadioButton(fContext);
    rb.setId(num++);
    rg.addView(rb); // the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead
    // of the layout
    firstRowTxtLayout.addView(rg);// you add the whole RadioGroup to the
    // layout
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


        }
    });

}
```

When I initilize the `rg = new RadioGroup(fContext);` outside I am getting:

```
`IllegalStateException`. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first while using RadioGroup
```

Logcat with line of code:

```
03-12 14:05:35.266: W/System.err(32734):    at com.vipera.ts.gui.custom.comVisaApprovalList.createRadioButton(comVisaApprovalList.java:531) firstRowTxtLayout.addView(rg);
03-12 14:05:35.266: W/System.err(32734):    at com.vipera.ts.gui.custom.comVisaApprovalList.constructRow(comVisaApprovalList.java:459)createRadioButton(rbTagincreament++);
03-12 14:05:35.271: W/System.err(32734):    at com.vipera.ts.gui.custom.comVisaApprovalList.createTableLayout(comVisaApprovalList.java:411)
03-12 14:05:35.271: W/System.err(32734):    at com.vipera.ts.gui.custom.comVisaApprovalList.init(comVisaApprovalList.java:121)
```

Comment: is rbButton's parent the linear layout? If so you may need to firstRowTxtLayout.removeView(rbButton)

Comment: What loop are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

`rbButton` is currently in another view, that's why the **exception**. You have to **call** `parent_of_rbButton.removeView(rbButton)` before you can add it to `rbGroup`.